# Python2: arguments after *argv

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found strange difference between py2 and py3

Please see piece of code:
https://github.com/DoumanAsh/collectionScripts/blob/master/python/art/trace.py#L101

When i attempt to import class with this method in py2:

```
from trace import EventTracer3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "trace.py", line 101
   def trace(self, event, *argv, frame=None):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But it is ok for py3.
I wasn't able to find whenever there are any limitations in function's arguments in py2...
It is actually a bit strange since as far as i know there should not be any differences between python2 and python3 in regard of function declaration. Am i wrong or right?

Comment: This is PEP 3102 if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intentional, and documented. See [the Python 2 grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html):

```
parameters: '(' [varargslist] ')'
varargslist: ((fpdef ['=' test] ',')*
              ('*' NAME [',' '**' NAME] | '**' NAME) |
              fpdef ['=' test] (',' fpdef ['=' test])* [','])
```

...so, you could have your regular arguments, comma-separated, **followed by** either `*NAME`, `*NAME, **NAME` or `**NAME` -- and that had to be the end of your argument list.

You can also see the [Python 2 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)'s description of kwargs:

> When a **final** formal parameter of the form **name is present, [...]

...emphasis added; in Python 2, kwargs were required to be the last parameter in a list.

---

Python 3.0 introduced [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/), which added keyword-only arguments which could follow the vararg list; this is what your example code uses.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It's a bit inconvenient for my needs. Guess i will need to make some sorta workaround to make it work on py2